# How to check if a player is in an area in unity without using collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Hi I'm creating a 2D game within unity and one of the issues I'm having is knowing where the player is so I can hide assets or move the player on top of them/behind them when necessary.

I've tried collision but it seems like there are issues.

For instance if there is a bed then when the player is at the foot of the bed I would like the players layer to be behind then beds layer but if they walk onto the bed for their layer to be on top of the bed.
I used collision to make something like this:

```
 public bool OutsideVisible = false;
    public GameObject Level1Outside;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
        {
            if (col.gameObject.name == "Player leaves apartment") <-name of trigger that is at the door of the apartment
            {
                OutsideVisible = true;
                    Level1Outside.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);}
```

Which was fine within a doorway as I could put a collider on the other side to check when they leave but I want to be able detect when the player leaves without having to surround every object with colliders especially as sometimes they might jut up against each other.

In my head the code would be something like:
Is player within bed region?
if yes set bed layer to 5
if no set bed layer to 6

Is player within wall region?
if yes set wall to not render
if no set wall to render

Answer (score 0):

you can keep using OnTriggerEnter2D when Player enters a collider and when it exits that specific collider you can just use the `OnTriggerExit2D` function

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player leaves apartment"){
        // do your stuff
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried something like that: void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{ 
        if (col.gameObject.name == "MC apartment bedroom wall")
        {
            Bedroomwall.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    
        if (col.gameObject.name == "MC apartment bedroom wall")
        {
            Bedroomwall.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
 }
} but im getting an issue where its saying that the object is being activated and deactived at the same time causing the game to stop running if I enter the collision area